# Any possible view previous deleted users in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Any possible view previous deleted users details in wordpress or restore previews users. Any plugin or any other idea. I have no DB backup.

Comment: previews?  Do you mean previous?  Once they're deleted, they're gone from the database.  Without a backup, it's not possible.

Comment: Sorry. previous user.

Comment: Ok; that's what I understood.  Without a backup it's not possible - when they're deleted from the admin console they're deleted from the database.